# Time not displaying on Obout Calender control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, toolbox, obout

I am using an obout calender control in asp.net using c#.I have set the code for the control using this tutorial Obout http://www.obout.com/calendar/tutorial_settime.aspx.I am using this control as I require the time and date to be obtained from a user but it only selects the date, it shows the time picker and allows you to set a time it just doesn't display in the text box.

What I want it to do is display the start time and date, but so far only the date is working.

```
<td class="question">
   Start Date & Time
</td>
<td>
   <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDate" CssClass="answer" MaxLength="50" Width="100px"/>
   <span class="mandatory">*</span>
   <obout:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server"
                   DatePickerMode="true"
                   TextBoxId="txtDate"
                   ShowTimeSelector="true"
                   TextSelectTime="Set Time">
   </obout:Calendar>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="question">
   Finish Date and Time
</td>
<td>
   <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxtFinish" CssClass="answer" MaxLength="50" Width="100px"/>
   <span class="mandatory">*</span>
   <obout:Calendar ID="Calendar2" runat="server"
                   DatePickerMode="true"
                   TextBoxId="TxtFinish"
                   ShowTimeSelector="true"
                   TextSelectTime="Set Time">
   </obout:Calendar>
```

Comment: As for finish date - you misspelled TextBoxID. Your is TxtFinish. First char is capital

Comment: Thanks Its changed now, anyone know why time isn't displaying?